# Display formula when cell is clicked vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I have something like this:

```
     A     B     C
1    11    12    13
2    10    20    15
3    1     -8    -2
```

So `A3`, `B3`, and `C3` is generated by subtracting `A1` to `A2` and so on.

If you look at the top of the sheet there is a long bar that shows the formula of a cell when you click on one. If you fill in the sheet manually, you can type in that bar something like `= A1 - A2` and it will fill `A3` for you.

Right now, because my formula is actually in the code, when I click on `A3` for example, the bar only shows `1` instead of `= A1 - A2`.

How do I get the formula to be displayed in the bar?

Comment: Instead of using VBA to generate the values inside of a particular cell, you can use it to dynamically write the formulas inside of the cell, as you would if you hadn't used VBA at all. In addition to showing you the formula, however, it will automatically update when data changes (whereas values dumped from a macro would not update). This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .formula for your requirement

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Formula = "=A1-A2"
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that right now, you're filling your cell along the lines of:

```
Range("A3").Value = Range("A1").Value - Range("A2").Value
```

So solve your Problem, use this:

```
Range("A3").FormulaLocal = "=SUM(A1;A2)"
```